# Is it possible to add custom method type to protobuf service?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, amqp

When you describe service with protobuf, you can add rpc methods. Is it possible to write some extension to use custom method type like:

```
service SomeService {
    rpc SomeRPCMethod(Request) returns (Response);
    amqp SomeAMQPMethod(AMQPRequest);
}
```

I found some information according to extending methods and service options but nothing about custom method types.

Comment: do you want the `SomeAMQPMethod` method to essentially be a wrapper to `SomeRPCMethod`? And the `AMQPRequest` is converted to a `Request`?

Comment: @colminator I would like to write some kind of plugin which will generate consumer and producer by this definition. This code will have nothing common with GRPC endpoints.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The `protoc-gen-go` tool will generate Go code for a `.proto` file definition like the one you have above. Provided all the `Message` (aka types) are defined this Go code will include client and server interfaces. These are typically used in gRPC implementations - but the interfaces could be implemented natively, mimicking a client-server model, without hitting any network. Is this the direction you are looking at?

Comment: @colminator I know that protoc is used for generating gRPC server and client. I would like to do almost the same but for amqp. I don't wont to generate an amqp-rpoxy which will listen events and then send messages to gRPC endpoint. In the example above I would like to generate common gRPC code for `rpc` method directive and I would like to write a plugin which will process `amqp` method directive and will generate special code for consumer and producer.

Comment: As a work example where I would like to use this: for example I would like to create some `mailService` with consumer which will process messages for sending emails and also I would like to have gRPC endpoint which will return success/fail statistic. Basically I would like to use this proto file like common server definition.

Comment: So you *do* want gRPC definitions created. But you also want add supplemental methods (for `amqp`)?

Comment: I want gRPC definitions for `rpc` methods and only consumer definitions for `amqp`. I mean I don't want generate gRPC definition for `amqp`

Comment: I say so because I saw as people generate HTTP endpoint which is just a proxy to gRPC endpoint. I don't want to do the same but with AMQP instead of HTTP. But if I won't find the solution how to properly process `amqp` keyword I'll definitely try to implement AMQP proxy

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use standard definitions in order to build a portable proto file. At end of the day that is the final goal of GRPC